# How to extract a fixed set of frames from a live video stream for machine learning prediction in PyTorch?

Tags: machine-learning, video, ffmpeg, pytorch, computer-vision

I recently created a [Video Swin Transformer](https://github.com/SwinTransformer/Video-Swin-Transformer) model that takes in a ([batch_size], 3, 32, 224, 224) [batch_size, channel, temporal_dim, height, width] tensor for video and outputs logits. The goal is to have the model predict on a live stream from a camera. Is there any way to capture the fixed sequence of 32 frames repetitively and have the model predict on a live stream. If prediction time is longer than 32 frames, can I stretch out the frames over a longer time period like a minute? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use my library [ffmpegio](https://github.com/python-ffmpegio/python-ffmpegio), which suits your need:

To install:

```
pip install ffmpegio
```

To get block of 32 frames from your input url

```py
import ffmpegio

url = 'input stream url'
temporal_dim = 32
height = 224
width = 224
size = [width,height]
pix_fmt = 'rgb24'

with ffmpegio.open(url,'rv',blocksize=temporal_dim,s=size,pix_fmt=pix_fmt) as stream:

    for frames in stream: # frames in [time,height,width,ch] ndarray
        vswim_in = frames.transpose(3,0,1,2) # reorg for your library
```

You can specify any other ffmpeg options as you wish to add (like a scaling/cropping filter to make input frame 224px square or input stream options).

Caveat. I haven't tested live stream buffering extensively. If you encounter any issues, please post an issue on the GitHub.